# Fontawesome icon not display

Tags: jsp, internet-explorer, icons, font-awesome

I'm using font awesome for my web application. I tested my web application on IE 11 on 2 different machine(notebook). One machine displaying the font awesome correctly, but the other machine do not display the icon. At first I thought there was a problem in my web application, after search the issue through various of forum, it still does not resolve the problem. Then I open [font awesome official website](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/) from both machine and one machine display the icon and the other one does not display the icon just like below image

**Machine 1 (Working Fine)**

[image]

**Machine 2 (Not Display the Icon)**

[image]

I hope somebody can help me resolve this issue. FYI, both machine using the same version of IE.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue with a Windows 8.1 and a Windows 2012 system both using IE 11 and only one would display the icons. After much investigation I couldn't find any answers.

I ended up restoring all IE settings and that fixed it. Unfortunately I do not have a reason or a specific setting that was causing this but it did correct it.

Internet Options -> Advanced -> Reset

I checked the box for "Delete Personal Settings" and then click reset.

Comment: My team and I were having the same issue and we solved it in a very similar manner. We have no idea what caused it, but resetting the browser's security settings fixed it.